# Iphone navigation bar change title?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, title

How do I change the title text on an Iphone navigation bar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
viewController.title = @"title text";
```

Answer (score -1):

You also can use this code:

```
[[self navigationItem]setTitle:self.title];
```